# MAGMA in google colab

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory, magma

i always get the following error "Error in magma_getdevice_arch: MAGMA not initialized (call magma_init() first) or bad device" whenever i run a very simple code using google colab with magma-2.6.1 installed.

////////////////////////

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cublas_v2.h"
#include "magma_v2.h"     
#include "magma_lapack.h" 

using namespace std;
int main ( int argc , char **argv ){

 magma_init();

magma_getdevice_arch(); 

magma_finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this issue has to do with a version of PyTorch too new for the version of CUDA installed on Colab Systems.

Run `pip install --user torch==1.9.0 torchvision==0.10.0 torchaudio==0.9.0 torchtext==0.10.0` to downgrade.

Answer taken from: https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/279990